# Override mail function in rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use this class for Action Mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "something@example.com",
          reply_to: 'whatever@example.com'

  def mail_method
    mail(to: 'email@example.com', subject: "SUBJECT")
  end
end
```

So like this I got many classes and methods which send emails like this from smtp delivery method.

But now I want to perform_deliveries , i.e. send emails only on production environment not in development or test environment.

So for that I want to use my email only, which is why I need to override mail method.

Things I have tried.

-> Making a function to return email, where function name is get_right_email

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "something@example.com",
          reply_to: 'whatever@example.com'

  def mail_method
    mail(to: get_right_email('email@example.com'), subject: "SUBJECT")
  end
end
```

And definition of get_right_email is as follows:

```
def get_right_email(email)
  if(Rails.env=='production')
    return email
  else 
    return 'myPersonalEmail@example.com'
  end
end
```

It would need some refactoring but it is still manageable. Will take a few hours and I can do, but is there a quicker way where I can just override mail function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config > enviroments folder you should have a file for production, development and test. Here you can specify your settings for each one.

Settings in these folders overide those in config > application.rb

For example when testing I don't usually actually send the emails but I do want to be able to test the emails so I use

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

This makes the emails accessible by calling ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

You can set the default from email address in these files as well using:

```
config.action_mailer.default_options = {
  :from => "foo@bar.com"
}
```

Theres a gem called letter_opener managed by the fantastic Ryan Bates which instead of sending an email in development opens the email in a new tab. This makes testing out emails in development a breeze.

[Letter Opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener)

UPDATE BELOW ------

Apologies, I didn't quite follow what you were looking for.

Rails has webhooks you can use to intercept emails and redirect them. You'll want to use an environment different than production.

The test environment is typically used for automated testing, to keep things clear you might want to consider setting up a new environment (eg: staging).

To create a new environment just create a new file in config/environments/ and give it a suitable name - eg: staging.rb

You can then call Rails.env.staging? where ever you like.

Anyway back to the main event...

To intercept the emails first create an intercept class:

```
class StagingEmailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.to = ['my@email.com']
  end
end
```

and then create an initializer file, eg:

config/initializers/staging_email_interceptor.rb

and inside do this:

```
if Rails.env.staging?
  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(StagingEmailInterceptor)
end
```

That way all emails sent in the staging environment will be sent to your email.

Comment: Thanks, its great for development. I will probably use it. But what about test environment? testing server doesn't even have a browser, even if it does, no one access it because it is a box, a VM instance.

Comment: What is it that you'd like to happen in the test environment?

Comment: the email should be sent to me in test environment